Is it possible to force nginx to resolve a hostname directly from the /etc/hosts file prior of proxying the requests to that host?
What I'm trying to achieve is to proxy pass the requests through an nginx reverse proxy instance, to a remote server that has a dynamic ip assigned to it.
I am able to update dynamically the /etc/hosts mappings, but whenever the IP changes, nginx is not refreshing the in memory mappings, failing any subsequent proxy requests. If I restart the nginx instance after  the /etc/hosts mappings were updated, it will start working again. I don't want to do this, if possible.
My nginx proxy location definition is something on this line:
location / {
        set $backend https://my.virtual.domain$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_pass $backend;
        include proxy_params;
    }

If possible I would prefer a solution that will not require the installation of a local DNS server. I need something that will instruct nginx to just read the /etc/hosts file content from time to time.
/etc/hosts mapping
#.#.#.#  my.virtual.domain

Thanks

What system do you use? Don't you have systemd?

I've ended up using the hot nginx reload option, which is just instructing nginx to reload the settings. When calling the reload, the hosts file new content is also loaded.
From what I've managed to find, the functionality that I was looking for,  seems to be available only in the commercial version of nginx: the resolve attribute.
I am not willing to pay just for this functionality at the moment, so I will stick with the hot reload, for now.
